# How change Address of NTP server for nodes by shell command?

Tags: maas, ntp

UBUNTU 16.04

MAAS 2.0.0 Beta 3

It seems the MAAS web interface doesnot update Address of NTP server for nodes in setting page? How can I change this NTP address by shell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your MAAS server via SSH. Get API key from your administrator account (take a look to the top right corner in the web GUI) and run the following command:

```
maas login my-mass http://localhost/MAAS
```

Set NTP server value:

```
maas my-maas maas set-config name=ntp_server value=your-preferred-ntp-server
```

Get NTP server value:

```
maas my-maas maas get-config name=ntp_server
```